# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException'

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to make a directory list using jQueryUI tabs and menu widgets. I have got the following code for obtaining the directory.

```
<?php 

     $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$databaseName, 
                    $user, 
                    $password,
                    array(
                        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
                        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
                  )
               );

    $menu = '';
    $charTabs = '<div id="charTabs">'; //1
    $db->exec('set names utf8');
    $queryFirstLetters = $db->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(organization, 1) as org FROM Organizations WHERE parent_id = 0 ORDER BY organization', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true));

    //Add each first characters to the charTabs
    $queryFirstLetters->execute();
    $charTabs .='<ul>'; //2
    while($rowFL = $queryFirstLetters->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
    { 
        $charTabs .= '<li><a href="#' . $rowFL['org'] . '">' . $rowFL['b'] . '</a></li>';//3
    }   
    $charTabs .= '</ul>'; //4

    //Create Divs corresponding to list items for each first letter.
    $queryFirstLetters->execute();
    while($rowFL = $queryFirstLetters->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    { 
        $charTabs .= '<div id="' . $rowFL['org'] . '">'; //5

        //Get the parent organizations and add their children as sub menu items
        $queryParentOrganizations = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM Organizations WHERE parent_id = 0 AND LEFT(organization,1) = :p1 ORDER BY organization', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true));
        $queryParentOrganizations->bindValue(':p1', $rowFL['org'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        //This is the line 26 which crashes
        $queryParentOrganizations->execute(); 
        //This is the line 26 which crashes
        echo '<script>$(function(){ $("#menu'.$rowFL['org'].'").menu(); });</script>';
        $menu = '<ul id="menu'.$rowFL['org'].'">';
        while($rowPO = $queryParentOrganizations->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $queryChildOrganizations = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM Organizations WHERE parent_id = :p1 ORDER BY organization', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true));
            $queryChildOrganizations->bindValue(':p1', $rowPO['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $queryChildOrganizations->execute();

            $menu .= '<li><a class="list" href="#">'.$rowPO['organization'].'</a>';
            if ($queryChildOrganizations->rowCount() > 0 )
            {
                $menu .= '<ul>';
                while($rowCO = $queryChildOrganizations->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                {
                    $menu .= '<li><a class="list" href="#' . $rowCO['id'] . '">' . $rowCO['organization'] . '</a></li>';
                }
                $menu .= '</ul>';
            }
            else
            {
                $menu .= '</li>';
            }
        }
        $menu .= '</ul>';
        $charTabs .= $menu . '</div>';
    }
    $charTabs .= '</div>';

    echo $charTabs;
?>
```

Ignoring the preformance issuses, it works fine. But after uploading to the server I got the following errors which is related to PDO.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while
>   other unbuffered queries are active.  Consider using
>   PDOStatement::fetchAll().  Alternatively, if your code is only ever
>   going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting
>   the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.' in
>   /home/server/public_html/directory/index.php:26
>
> Stack trace:
>
> `#`0 /home/server/public_html/directory/index.php(26): PDO->prepare('SELECT * FROM O...')
>
> `#`1 /home/server/public_html/directory/index.php(26): include('/home/server/publ...')
>
> `#`2 {main} thrown in /home/server/public_html/directory/index.php on line 26

Comment: If I used mysql_* functions it should have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using `PDOStatement::fetchAll()`. Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY` attribute.

Comment: Obviously OP doesn't understand that.

Comment: Well I tried to use `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY` attribute. But it does not change anything. I got the same error message.

Comment: 1. You might try it the wrong way. Why didn't you include what have you tried in your question? 2. There is another solution proposed by this exceptionally through error message.

Comment: @YourCommonSense it is already included what I have tried. Can't you see?